# Return a dictionary within nested dictionaries / lists, which contains a specific value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I am trying to get the recipe ingredients and instructions from recipe websites. Often these websites utilize a hrecipe format that can be found in a `<script type="application/ld+json">` tag and they all have the `"@type": "Recipe"`. The problem is they are sometimes in a simple list or dict and sometimes they are in nested dicts/lists. I am wondering what is the best way to loop through all the lists/dicts until it finds the `"Recipe"` value in `"@type": "Recipe"` and return that entire dictionary so I can get then parse it for the `recipeInstructions` and `recipeIngredient` data?

Example 1:

```
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "Recipe",
    "aggregateRating": {},
    "author": {
        "@context": "https://schema.org",
        "@type": "person",
        "name": "Tiffany Page"
    },
    "cookTime": "PT55M",
    "cookingMethod": null,
    "dateCreated": "2021-08-09",
    "dateModified": "2021-08-09",
    "datePublished": "2021-08-09",
    "description": "This super easy creamy quiche is a simple weeknight dinner. Serve with a salad or chips on the side.",
    "image": {
        "@context": "https://schema.org",
        "@type": "ImageObject",
        "height": 1320,
        "url": "https://img.bestrecipes.com.au/XB9GK7i4/br/2021/08/creamy-quiche-diane-963734-1.jpg",
        "width": 1980
    },
    "keywords": "mustard, cream, brown, sauce, cheese, thickened, olive, oil, onion, pastry, creamy quiche diane recipe",
    "mainEntityOfPage": null,
    "name": "Creamy quiche diane recipe",
    "nutrition": {
        "@context": "https://schema.org",
        "@type": "NutritionInformation",
        "calories": null,
        "carbohydrateContent": null,
        "cholesterolContent": null,
        "fatContent": null,
        "fibreContent": null,
        "proteinContent": null,
        "saturatedFatContent": null,
        "sodiumContent": null,
        "sugarContent": null
    },
    "prepTime": "PT10M",
    "publisher": {
        "@context": "https://schema.org",
        "@type": "Organization",
        "logo": {
            "@context": "https://schema.org",
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "height": 70,
            "url": "https://www.bestrecipes.com.au/assets/static/site-logos/br.png",
            "width": 218
        },
        "name": "Australia's Best Recipes"
    },
    "recipeCategory": null,
    "recipeCuisine": null,
    "recipeIngredient": [
        "2 sheets store bought pastry",
        "1 tbsp olive oil",
        "1 medium brown onion, finely sliced",
        "200g swiss brown mushrooms, sliced",
        "100g (1 cup) 3 cheese blend",
        "5 eggs",
        "400ml thickened cream",
        "1 tbsp Worcestershire sauce",
        "2 tsp Dijon mustard"
    ],
    "recipeInstructions": [
        "Preheat oven to 220C/200C fan forced.",
        "Place a sheet of pastry on a lightly floured surface. Place the second sheet on top, dust with flour and roll out to a 30cm square. Line a 21cm (base measurement) fluted, loose bottomed round tart tin and trim excess leaving a little of the pastry overhanging the rim. Place a sheet of baking paper over the pastry and fill with baking beans or rice. Bake for 10-15 minutes, remove the beans and bake for a further 5 minutes or until golden. Reduce oven temp to 170C fan forced.",
        "Heat oil in a medium frying pan over a medium high heat. Add the onion and cook for 3-4 minutes or until golden. Add the mushrooms and cook for 5 minutes. Leave to cool before spooning into the cooked tart case. Sprinkle with cheese.",
        "Whisk the eggs in a large bowl. Add the cream, Worcestershire sauce and Dijon mustard and whisk to combine. Pour over the mushrooms and sprinkle with chives. Bake for 35-40 minutes or until set. Leave to cool slightly before cutting into wedges to serve."
    ],
    "recipeYield": 6,
    "totalTime": "PT65M",
    "video": null
}
```

Example 2:
Inside a list:

```
[
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
        "itemListElement": [
            {
                "@type": "ListItem",
                "item": {
                    "@id": "https://www.allrecipes.com/",
                    "image": null,
                    "name": "Home"
                },
                "position": 1
            },
            {
                "@type": "ListItem",
                "item": {
                    "@id": "https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/",
                    "image": null,
                    "name": "Recipes"
                },
                "position": 2
            },
            {
                "@type": "ListItem",
                "item": {
                    "@id": "https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/92/meat-and-poultry/",
                    "image": null,
                    "name": "Meat and Poultry"
                },
                "position": 3
            },
            {
                "@type": "ListItem",
                "item": {
                    "@id": "https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/201/meat-and-poultry/chicken/",
                    "image": null,
                    "name": "Chicken"
                },
                "position": 4
            },
            {
                "@type": "ListItem",
                "item": {
                    "@id": "https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/659/meat-and-poultry/chicken/chicken-breasts/",
                    "image": null,
                    "name": "Breast"
                },
                "position": 5
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "Recipe",
        "aggregateRating": {
            "@type": "AggregateRating",
            "bestRating": "5",
            "itemReviewed": "Spicy Buttermilk Baked Chicken",
            "ratingCount": 1,
            "ratingValue": 5,
            "worstRating": "1"
        },
        "author": [
            {
                "@type": "Person",
                "name": "Rogerson"
            }
        ],
        "cookTime": "P0DT0H40M",
        "datePublished": "2020-03-20T06:50:32.000Z",
        "description": "This buttermilk baked chicken is not breaded - yum!",
        "image": {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "height": 2736,
            "url": "https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fimages.media-allrecipes.com%2Fuserphotos%2F6715576.jpg",
            "width": 3648
        },
        "mainEntityOfPage": "https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/273860/spicy-buttermilk-baked-chicken/",
        "name": "Spicy Buttermilk Baked Chicken",
        "nutrition": {
            "@type": "NutritionInformation",
            "calories": "298.2 calories",
            "carbohydrateContent": "27.8 g",
            "cholesterolContent": "65.7 mg",
            "fatContent": "7.5 g",
            "fiberContent": "0.1 g",
            "proteinContent": "31 g",
            "saturatedFatContent": "1.3 g",
            "servingSize": null,
            "sodiumContent": "3976.8 mg",
            "sugarContent": "5.9 g",
            "transFatContent": null,
            "unsaturatedFatContent": null
        },
        "prepTime": "P0DT0H5M",
        "recipeCategory": [
            "Meat and Poultry",
            "Chicken",
            "Breast"
        ],
        "recipeCuisine": [],
        "recipeIngredient": [
            "2 cups buttermilk",
            "2 cups Buffalo wing sauce (such as Frank's\u00ae)",
            "2 tablespoons Dijon mustard",
            "1 clove garlic, minced",
            "\u00bd teaspoon salt",
            "\u00bc teaspoon ground black pepper",
            "4 skinless, boneless chicken breast halves",
            "cooking spray"
        ],
        "recipeInstructions": [
            {
                "@type": "HowToStep",
                "text": "Whisk buttermilk, Buffalo sauce, mustard, garlic, salt, and pepper together in a shallow bowl. Add chicken. Cover and marinate in the refrigerator for 12 to 24 hours.\n"
            },
            {
                "@type": "HowToStep",
                "text": "Preheat the oven to 375 degrees F (190 degrees C). Grease a 9x13-inch baking dish.\n"
            },
            {
                "@type": "HowToStep",
                "text": "Pour chicken and marinade into the prepared baking dish.\n"
            },
            {
                "@type": "HowToStep",
                "text": "Bake in the preheated oven until juices run clear, about 40 minutes. An instant-read thermometer inserted into the center should read at least 165 degrees F (74 degrees C).\n"
            }
        ],
        "recipeYield": "4 servings",
        "review": [
            {
                "@type": "Review",
                "author": {
                    "@type": "Person",
                    "image": null,
                    "name": "Soup Loving Nicole",
                    "sameAs": "https://www.allrecipes.com/cook/souplovingnicole/"
                },
                "datePublished": "2019-06-08T23:04:27.557Z",
                "reviewBody": "Made as written and this turned out tender and great! I sliced the leftovers and used it to top a garden salad the next day for lunch and that was awesome too. Thanks for sharing!",
                "reviewRating": {
                    "@type": "Rating",
                    "bestRating": "5",
                    "ratingValue": 5,
                    "worstRating": "1"
                }
            }
        ],
        "totalTime": "P0DT12H45M"
    }
]
```

Example 3:

Sometimes they are nested inside dicts and lists:

```
{
"@context": "https://schema.org",
"@graph": [
    {
        "@id": "https://www.mynewroots.org/site/#website",
        "@type": "WebSite",
        "description": "How to make healthy choices every day",
        "inLanguage": "en-US",
        "name": "My New Roots",
        "potentialAction": [
            {
                "@type": "SearchAction",
                "query-input": "required name=search_term_string",
                "target": {
                    "@type": "EntryPoint",
                    "urlTemplate": "https://www.mynewroots.org/site/?s={search_term_string}"
                }
            }
        ],
        "url": "https://www.mynewroots.org/site/"
    },
    {
        "@id": "https://www.mynewroots.org/site/2021/10/wild-rice-and-butternut-blessings/#primaryimage",
        "@type": "ImageObject",
        "contentUrl": "https://www.mynewroots.org/site/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/header-scaled.jpg",
        "height": 1347,
        "inLanguage": "en-US",
        "url": "https://www.mynewroots.org/site/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/header-scaled.jpg",
        "width": 2560
    },
    {
        "@id": "https://www.mynewroots.org/site/2021/10/wild-rice-and-butternut-blessings/#webpage",
        "@type": "WebPage",
        "author": {
            "@id": "https://www.mynewroots.org/site/#/schema/person/d9322b8a1a1138da07906bf21792dd09"
        },
        "breadcrumb": {
            "@id": "https://www.mynewroots.org/site/2021/10/wild-rice-and-butternut-blessings/#breadcrumb"
        },
        "dateModified": "2021-10-05T17:51:02+00:00",
        "datePublished": "2021-10-05T17:26:47+00:00",
        "description": "Wild rice and butternut squash with toasted walnut sauce come together for a beautiful autumnal dish with an important story and message",
        "inLanguage": "en-US",
        "isPartOf": {
            "@id": "https://www.mynewroots.org/site/#website"
        },
        "name": "Wild Rice and Butternut Blessings - My New Roots",
        "potentialAction": [
            {
                "@type": "ReadAction",
                "target": [
                    "https://www.mynewroots.org/site/2021/10/wild-rice-and-butternut-blessings/"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "primaryImageOfPage": {
            "@id": "https://www.mynewroots.org/site/2021/10/wild-rice-and-butternut-blessings/#primaryimage"
        },
        "url": "https://www.mynewroots.org/site/2021/10/wild-rice-and-butternut-blessings/"
    },
    {
        "@id": "https://www.mynewroots.org/site/2021/10/wild-rice-and-butternut-blessings/#breadcrumb",
        "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
        "itemListElement": [
            {
                "@type": "ListItem",
                "item": "https://www.mynewroots.org/site/",
                "name": "Home",
                "position": 1
            },
            {
                "@type": "ListItem",
                "name": "Wild Rice and Butternut Blessings",
                "position": 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "@id": "https://www.mynewroots.org/site/#/schema/person/d9322b8a1a1138da07906bf21792dd09",
        "@type": "Person",
        "image": {
            "@id": "https://www.mynewroots.org/site/#personlogo",
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "caption": "Sarah Britton",
            "contentUrl": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/f98fa19eb99c296da286267aacaf64de?s=96&d=mm&r=g",
            "inLanguage": "en-US",
            "url": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/f98fa19eb99c296da286267aacaf64de?s=96&d=mm&r=g"
        },
        "name": "Sarah Britton",
        "url": "https://www.mynewroots.org/site/author/sarah-britton/"
    },
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org/",
        "@id": "https://www.mynewroots.org/site/2021/10/wild-rice-and-butternut-blessings/#recipe",
        "@type": "Recipe",
        "aggregateRating": {
            "@type": "AggregateRating",
            "ratingCount": "5",
            "ratingValue": "5"
        },
        "author": {
            "@type": "Person",
            "name": "Sarah Britton"
        },
        "datePublished": "2021-10-05T13:26:47+00:00",
        "description": "",
        "isPartOf": {
            "@id": "https://www.mynewroots.org/site/2021/10/wild-rice-and-butternut-blessings/#webpage"
        },
        "mainEntityOfPage": "https://www.mynewroots.org/site/2021/10/wild-rice-and-butternut-blessings/#webpage",
        "name": "Wild Rice and Butternut Blessings\u00a0with Mushrooms, Toasted Walnut Garlic Sauce, and Sumac",
        "recipeIngredient": [
            "4 lb. / 2kg butternut squash (about 1 large, try to find one with a long neck!)",
            "1 cup / 175g wild rice (soaked for at least 12 hours)",
            "9 oz. / 250g mixed wild mushrooms (or any mushroom of your choice)",
            "3 cloves garlic (minced)",
            "a couple sprigs fresh thyme and rosemary",
            "\u00bd cup / 13g chopped flat-leaf parsley",
            "1  batch Toasted Walnut Sauce (recipe follows)",
            "1 Tbsp. sumac (divided)",
            "freshly cracked black pepper",
            "handful of walnuts (for garnish if desired)",
            "1 cup / 125g raw walnuts",
            "1  garlic clove",
            "2 Tbsp. cold-pressed olive oil",
            "4 tsp. apple cider vinegar",
            "2 tsp. pure maple syrup",
            "2  generous pinches of fine sea salt (plus more as needed)"
        ],
        "recipeInstructions": [
            {
                "@type": "HowToStep",
                "name": "Start by cooking the wild rice: drain and rinse the soaked rice well, place in a pot. Add 3 cups / 750ml of fresh water, a couple pinches of sea salt, then bring to a boil, and reduce to simmer. Cook until rice is chewy-tender \u2013 about 45 minutes.",
                "text": "Start by cooking the wild rice: drain and rinse the soaked rice well, place in a pot. Add 3 cups / 750ml of fresh water, a couple pinches of sea salt, then bring to a boil, and reduce to simmer. Cook until rice is chewy-tender \u2013 about 45 minutes.",
                "url": "https://www.mynewroots.org/site/2021/10/wild-rice-and-butternut-blessings/#wprm-recipe-5340-step-0-0"
            },
            {
                "@type": "HowToStep",
                "name": "While the rice is cooking, preheat the oven to 350\u00b0F / 180\u00b0C. Spread the walnuts in a single layer on a rimmed baking sheet. Toast for 7 to 10 minutes, watching them carefully so they do not burn, until they are golden and fragrant. Remove from the oven and let cool slightly.",
                "text": "While the rice is cooking, preheat the oven to 350\u00b0F / 180\u00b0C. Spread the walnuts in a single layer on a rimmed baking sheet. Toast for 7 to 10 minutes, watching them carefully so they do not burn, until they are golden and fragrant. Remove from the oven and let cool slightly.",
                "url": "https://www.mynewroots.org/site/2021/10/wild-rice-and-butternut-blessings/#wprm-recipe-5340-step-0-1"
            },
            {
                "@type": "HowToStep",
                "name": "Turn the oven heat up to 400\u00b0F / 200\u00b0C. Give the butternut squash a good scrub, making sure to remove any dust or dirt. Leaving the skin on, slice the squash neck into rounds about 1\u201d / 2.5cm thick. Place on a baking sheet, sprinkle with a little salt, and roast in the oven for 20-30 minutes, flipping once halfway through cooking, until the squash is fork tender. Remove from the oven and drizzle with olive oil and a little more salt, if desired.\u00a0",
                "text": "Turn the oven heat up to 400\u00b0F / 200\u00b0C. Give the butternut squash a good scrub, making sure to remove any dust or dirt. Leaving the skin on, slice the squash neck into rounds about 1\u201d / 2.5cm thick. Place on a baking sheet, sprinkle with a little salt, and roast in the oven for 20-30 minutes, flipping once halfway through cooking, until the squash is fork tender. Remove from the oven and drizzle with olive oil and a little more salt, if desired.\u00a0",
                "url": "https://www.mynewroots.org/site/2021/10/wild-rice-and-butternut-blessings/#wprm-recipe-5340-step-0-2"
            },
            {
                "@type": "HowToStep",
                "name": "While the squash is roasting, make the Toasted Walnut Sauce. Place the toasted walnuts, garlic, olive oil, apple cider vinegar, and maple syrup in a blender.",
                "text": "While the squash is roasting, make the Toasted Walnut Sauce. Place the toasted walnuts, garlic, olive oil, apple cider vinegar, and maple syrup in a blender.",
                "url": "https://www.mynewroots.org/site/2021/10/wild-rice-and-butternut-blessings/#wprm-recipe-5340-step-0-3"
            },
            {
                "@type": "HowToStep",
                "name": "Blend on high, adding up to 1 cup / 250ml of water to thin the dressing as needed\u2014you are looking for the consistency of melted ice cream. Season with salt. Store in an airtight glass container in the fridge for up to 5 days.",
                "text": "Blend on high, adding up to 1 cup / 250ml of water to thin the dressing as needed\u2014you are looking for the consistency of melted ice cream. Season with salt. Store in an airtight glass container in the fridge for up to 5 days.",
                "url": "https://www.mynewroots.org/site/2021/10/wild-rice-and-butternut-blessings/#wprm-recipe-5340-step-0-4"
            },
            {
                "@type": "HowToStep",
                "name": "Lastly, prepare the mushrooms. Clean and cut the mushrooms as desired (I used king oyster mushrooms, sliced in half lengthwise and scored diagonally). Add a knob of your favourite cooking fat to a large skillet, and once melted add the mushrooms and a couple pinches of salt. Cook the mushrooms without crowding them, and do not move them about in the pan too much. You\u2019re looking for a nice sear and that comes after the mushrooms have been in constant, direct contact with high heat. Once golden on one side, flip, and continue cooking until golden on the other.",
                "text": "Lastly, prepare the mushrooms. Clean and cut the mushrooms as desired (I used king oyster mushrooms, sliced in half lengthwise and scored diagonally). Add a knob of your favourite cooking fat to a large skillet, and once melted add the mushrooms and a couple pinches of salt. Cook the mushrooms without crowding them, and do not move them about in the pan too much. You\u2019re looking for a nice sear and that comes after the mushrooms have been in constant, direct contact with high heat. Once golden on one side, flip, and continue cooking until golden on the other.",
                "url": "https://www.mynewroots.org/site/2021/10/wild-rice-and-butternut-blessings/#wprm-recipe-5340-step-0-5"
            },
            {
                "@type": "HowToStep",
                "name": "In a large bowl, combine the wild rice and parsley. Drizzle a touch of the sauce and about \u00bd Tbsp. of the sumac, a few grinds of black pepper, and fold to incorporate.",
                "text": "In a large bowl, combine the wild rice and parsley. Drizzle a touch of the sauce and about \u00bd Tbsp. of the sumac, a few grinds of black pepper, and fold to incorporate.",
                "url": "https://www.mynewroots.org/site/2021/10/wild-rice-and-butternut-blessings/#wprm-recipe-5340-step-0-6"
            },
            {
                "@type": "HowToStep",
                "name": "To assemble, drizzle or puddle some sauce on the bottom of your serving plate. Add a round of butternut squash, followed by the wild rice mixture, a couple mushrooms, then repeat the layers of squash, rice, mushrooms. Drizzle remaining sauce over top, sprinkle with additional sumac and black pepper, and a handful of walnuts.",
                "text": "To assemble, drizzle or puddle some sauce on the bottom of your serving plate. Add a round of butternut squash, followed by the wild rice mixture, a couple mushrooms, then repeat the layers of squash, rice, mushrooms. Drizzle remaining sauce over top, sprinkle with additional sumac and black pepper, and a handful of walnuts.",
                "url": "https://www.mynewroots.org/site/2021/10/wild-rice-and-butternut-blessings/#wprm-recipe-5340-step-0-7"
            },
            {
                "@type": "HowToStep",
                "name": "Say thank you and enjoy each bite, each grain.",
                "text": "Say thank you and enjoy each bite, each grain.",
                "url": "https://www.mynewroots.org/site/2021/10/wild-rice-and-butternut-blessings/#wprm-recipe-5340-step-0-8"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Comment: These looks like they're responses to different API functions. The format that's returned depends on what you're requesting.

Comment: Agreed, these are just from the DOM once a page loads, so every website will be different. So I am after a way to find the Recipe in the response despite the format.